# Write page number information to an external text file

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages, page, write-file

```
Here is page \pageref{here}\label{here}
```

`\pageref{here}\label{here}` can get the page number of the current location, I want to write it into a txt file, but writing directly will report an error, I want to know how to convert this variable so that it can be written into a txt file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspage,lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newwrite\myoutfile

\immediate\openout\myoutfile=\jobname-myoutfile.txt

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\immediate\write\myoutfile{\pageref{here}\label{here}.}

\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is already written to the aux file, you could simply extract it from there with `grep here foo.aux` or similar

Comment: but if you mean write that literal text (rather than the page number) then `\immediate\write\myoutfile{\detokenize{\pageref{here}\label{here}.}}`

Comment: But what I want to write is the page number obtained by this command

Comment: You can use zref or refcount to get expandable page references.

Comment: you don't need a label for that just use `\write\myoutfile{\thepage}`, but as I said in the first comment, why do you need a special file for this, if you do use `\label` then the information is written to the aux file.

Answer (score 1):

I added `!!!` just for debugging so you can see where the page write happened, on page 2 in this case:

[image]

The file written is

```
This was on page 2.
```

You just need to do a non-immediate `\write` to make sure that you get the correct number

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspage,lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newwrite\myoutfile

\immediate\openout\myoutfile=\jobname-myoutfile.txt

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

!!!\write\myoutfile{This was on page \thepage.}

\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}
```